# jooq single query with one to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have a table experiment and a table tags. There may be many tags for one experiment.
schema:

```
--------                  --------
|Table1|  1           n   |Table2|
|      | <--------------> |      |
|      |                  |      |
--------                  --------
(experiment)              (tags)
```

Is it possible to create a query with jooq which returns the experiments and the corresponding List of tags?

something like `Result<Record>` where Record is a experimentRecord and a list of Tags, or a `map<experimentRecord`, `List<TagRecord>`.

I also have a query which returns only one result, is there something convenient out there?

EDIT: java8, newest jooq.

Comment: Which Java version, which JooQ version? Also, what are your tables?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many ways to materialise a nested collection with SQL, and / or with jOOQ. I'm just going through some of them:

#### Using joins

If you don't deeply nest those collections, denormalising (flattening) your results with a `JOIN` might do the trick for you, without adding too much overhead as data is being duplicated. Essentially, you'll write:

```
Map<ExperimentRecord, Result<Record>> map =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(EXPERIMENT)
   .join(TAGS)
   .on(...)
   .fetchGroups(EXPERIMENT);
```

The above map contains experiment records as keys, and nested collections containing all the tags as values.

#### Creating two queries

If you want to materialise a complex object graph, using joins might no longer be optimal. Instead, you probably want to collect the data in your client from two distinct queries:

```
Result<ExperimentRecord> experiments = 
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(EXPERIMENT)
   .fetch();
```

And

```
Result<TagsRecord> tags =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(TAGS)
   .where(... restrict to the previous experiments ...)
   .fetch();
```

And now, merge the two results in your client's memory, e.g.

```
experiments.stream()
           .map(e -> new ExperimentWithTags(
                e, 
                tags.stream()
                    .filter(t -> e.getId().equals(t.getExperimentId()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
           ));
```

#### Nesting collections using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON

This question didn't require it, but others may find this question in search for a way of nesting to-many relationships with jOOQ. [I've provided an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64385482/521799). Starting with jOOQ 3.14, you can use your RDBMS's SQL/XML or SQL/JSON capabilities, and then use Jackson, Gson, or JAXB to nest collections like this:

```java
List<Experiment> experiments =
ctx.select(
      EXPERIMENT.asterisk(),
      field(
        select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(TAGS.fields())))
        .from(TAGS)
        .where(TAGS.EXPERIMENT_ID.eq(EXPERIMENT.ID))
      ).as("tags")
    )
   .from(EXPERIMENT)
   .fetchInto(Experiment.class);
```

Where `Experiment` is a custom Java class like this:

```java
class Experiment {
  long id;
  String name;
  List<Tag> tags;
}

class Tag {
  long id;
  String name;
}
```

#### Nesting collections using `MULTISET`

Even better than the above, [you can hide using SQL/XML or SQL/JSON behind jOOQ 3.15's new `MULTISET` operator support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/). Assuming the above Java classes are Java 16 records (or any other immutable classes), you can even map nested collections type safely into your DTOs:

```
List<Experiment> experiments =
ctx.select(
      EXPERIMENT.ID,
      EXPERIMENT.NAME,
      multiset(
        select(TAGS.ID, TAGS.NAME)
        .from(TAGS)
        .where(TAGS.EXPERIMENT_ID.eq(EXPERIMENT.ID))
      ).as("tags").convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Tag::new)))
    )
   .from(EXPERIMENT)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(Experiment::new));
```

Where `Experiment` is a custom Java class like this:

```java
record Experiment(long id, String name, List<Tag> tags) {}
record Tag(long id, String name) {}
```

[See also this blog post for more information](https://blog.jooq.org/2021/07/06/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/).

Comment: Thank you, i sometimes know i have only one result, is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: @Leander: I'm not sure what you mean... One result of what? `EXPERIMENT`? Or `TAGS`?

Comment: @Leander: I see. You can call `fetchOne()` or `fetchOptional()` rather than `fetch()` to get an individual record

Comment: But then there is no possiblity to grasp the TAGS collection?

Comment: @tfeiner: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "grasping the tags collection"...?

Comment: I think what Leander means it: What if I am sure that I have exactly ONE experiment with a collection of tags? (so that Map<ExperimentRecord, Result<Record>> has exactly one entry)

Comment: OK, I see, but I would still just fetch one experiment with `fetchOne()`, and then collect the tags in a second query for that... Anyway, I'm very happy to answer a concrete question, i.e. a question where the target structure is well defined. There are dozens of solutions, I'd prefer not to be guessing what the desired target structure really is.

Comment: I was able to fetch the many relationships just using `arrayAgg` without the json object wrapper of the TAGs field.

Comment: @OnomeSotu: Yes, you can do that, but I suspect it's equivalent to the `MULTISET` or `MULTISET_AGG` approach, which is more convenient on the jOOQ side.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [SimpleFlatMapper](http://simpleflatmapper.org/) to map your result to a `Tuple2<ExperimentRecord, List<TagRecord>>`. All you need to do is.

1 - create a mapper, specify the key column, assumed it would be id

```
JdbcMapper mapper = 
    JdbcMapperFactory
     .newInstance()
     .addKeys(EXPERIMENT.ID.getName())
     .newMapper(new TypeReference<Tuple2<ExperimentRecord, List<TagRecord>>>() {});
```

2 - use the mapper on the ResultSet of your query

```
try (ResultSet rs = DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(EXPERIMENT)
   .join(TAGS)
   .on(...)
   .fetchResultSet()) {
    Stream<Tuple2<ExperimentRecord, List<TagRecord>>> stream = mapper.stream(rs);
    ....
}
```

See [here](https://arnaudroger.github.io/blog/2017/03/02/jooq-one-to-many-without-dto.html) for more details