# Type safe mapping one-to-one and one-to-many relationships to records

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I want to map one-to-one and one-to-many relationships to generated Records, preferably in a type-safe manner.

I now have this working with Java records, but I would rather use the code generated Records, so I can update them easier afterwards, though I don't need all the columns of a Record.

I also have the problem that isn't doens't map the contacts to a List but to a List while it does map the Address correctly.

```java
record BulkContactEdit(long id, String organizationName, List < Contact > contacts, Address visitedAddress) {}

record Contact(long id) {}

record Address(long id, String address, String state, String city, String zipcode, Long country_id) {}

var bce = BULK_CONTACT_EDIT.as("bce");
var bceContacts = BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_CONTACTS.as("bceContacts");
var rel = RELATION.as("rel");

var bceAddress = ADDRESS.as("bceAddress");

var query = jooq().select(
bce.ID, bce.ORGANIZATION_NAME,
// For some reason this doesn't map.
//                DSL.multisetAgg(rel.ID)
//                    .as("contacts")
//                    .convertFrom(r -> r.map(mapping(Contact::new))),
jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(rel.ID)).as("contacts"), jsonObject(bceAddress.fields()).as("visitedAddress"))
// Same as above, but with redundant sub-query.
//                DSL.field(
//                        jooq()
//                            .select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(rel.ID)))
//                            .from(rel)
//                            .where(rel.ID.eq(bceContacts.CONTACT_ID)))
//                    .as("contacts"))
.from(
bce.join(bceContacts).on(bceContacts.BULK_CONTACT_EDIT_ID.eq(bce.ID)).join(rel).on(rel.ID.eq(bceContacts.CONTACT_ID)).leftJoin(bceAddress).on(bceAddress.ID.eq(bce.VISIT_ADDRESS_ID)).where(bce.ID.eq(bulkContactEditId)));

var bulkContactEdit = query.fetchOneInto(BulkContactEdit.class);
```

Comment: Regarding that problem you're having with `multisetAgg()`, which you also [mentioned in a comment to a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855430/521799), it's probably best to isolate that problem in a new question or [bug report](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose), though please do check if you're using the latest possible jOOQ version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regarding type safety

> I want to map one-to-one and one-to-many relationships to generated Records, preferably in a type-safe manner.

If you want type safety, you should not use 2 of the features you've used:

- Manual SQL/JSON API usage, which produces generic JSON documents that lack type safety
- Reflective mapping via `into(X.class)` calls, which make use of the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html)'s reflective mapping capabilities.

There's nothing wrong with the above approach. jOOQ 3.14 introduced SQL/JSON support as well as the capability of [mapping JSON documents to Java objects using Gson or Jackson](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/converter-provider/), if found on the classpath. The approach is just not type safe.

Now, let's look at your individual questions individually, you seem to be mixing concerns...

#### One-to-one mapping

Starting with jOOQ 3.17 (not yet released, but soon), [the `Table<R>` type extends `SelectField<R>` for convenience](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/), which means you can project any table expression as a nested record, and map it to your own custom record (or not):

```java
// Using implicit joins, mixing scalar values and nested records
Result<Record3<Long, String, AddressRecord>> r1 =
ctx.select(bce.ID, bce.ORGANIZATION_NAME, bce.address())
   .from(bce)
   .fetch();

// Using implicit joins, projecting only nested records
Result<Record2<BulkContactEditRecord, AddressRecord>> r1 =
ctx.select(bce, bce.address())
   .from(bce)
   .fetch();
```

While not necessary, the above example makes use of [implicit joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), which greatly simplify a query like this. Of course, you can continue using explicit joins like you did.

In jOOQ 3.16, you can do this via an explicit projection of a [nested `row()` expression](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/), like this. There is no type safety when mapping the nested record to a typed, generated `UpdatableRecord`, but I think that's acceptable, given that you're still using generated code and as such can't really have any mapping errors:

```java
// Using implicit joins, mixing scalar values and nested records
Result<Record3<Long, String, AddressRecord>> r1 =
ctx.select(
        bce.ID, 
        bce.ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
        row(bce.address().fields()).convertFrom(r -> r.into(ADDRESS)))
   .from(bce)
   .fetch();

// Using implicit joins, projecting only nested records
Result<Record2<BulkContactEditRecord, AddressRecord>> r1 =
ctx.select(
        row(bce.fields()).convertFrom(r -> r.into(BULK_CONTACT_EDIT)), 
        row(bce.address().fields()).convertFrom(r -> r.into(ADDRESS)))
   .from(bce)
   .fetch();
```

#### One-to-many mapping

There seems to have been something going wrong in your code when you used the `multisetAgg(rel.ID)` approach, but I can't see what could have been the problem from your question. Also, [it's not really a different question from your previous one, which already has an answer on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855430/521799).

The only difference between your two questions is that here, you prefer not to use a Java record, but jOOQ's generated records, in case of which you'll use this idiom:

```java
Field<Result<RelationRecord>> f = multisetAgg(rel.ID).convertFrom(r -> r.map(RELATION));
```